# How do I radio?

Tags: transmitter

What's the simplest way to make a radio station from my  home? I just want to bump this city with some slick tunes.

What do I need to buy and about how much am I to spend?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about broadcasting, which is not generally permitted as part of Amateur Radio.

Answer (score 4):

Transmitting on the FM broadcast band with any kind of power is illegal pretty much everywhere. Getting your ham license gives you some other bands to play with but music is only allowed on certain bands for very brief periods, ie, read "no pirate stations allowed".

That being said, [here's a 15W FM transmitter](https://dx.com/p/cze-15a-2w-15w-stereo-fm-audio-transmitter-w-antenna-for-car-silver-278498) that will cover one bloody large area with the right antenna, using it will however have you tracked pretty soon and facing a really big fine. Do with this what you will but they really do fine people for this.

Comment: I'd also mention that *broadcasting* is not allowed, as well as music not being allowed.